# Show django filter options according to the logged-in user

Tags: python, django

I’m new to Django and am trying to show filter options that are only relevant to the user - for example, my app has `Message` and `Automation` classes with a many:many relationship, but my filter shows a select option with automations created by other users rather than only those created by the logged-in user.

How can I get it to only show those created by the current user?

The view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'customer'], own_account_only=True)
def message_list(request, pk):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=pk)
    messages = account.message_set.all()
    filter = MessageFilter(request.GET, queryset=messages)
    messages = filter.qs
    context = {'account': account,
               'messages': messages, 'filter': filter}
    return render(request, 'messages/message_list.html', context)
```

The filter:

```
class MessageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Message  # model we’re building filter for
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['account', 'date_created', 'text', 'subject']
```

The classes:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField()
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    automations = models.ManyToManyField('automations.Automation', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Automation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the HTML:

```
<form method="get" class="filter-form with-ps hide">
  {{filter.form.as_p}}
  <button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

I’m assuming I need to edit the `messages` passed into `MessageFilter` to somehow exclude automations owned by all users, or somehow tell `MessageFilter` to only show automations etc of the current logged-in user?

Thank you.

Note: the image below shows the messages listed in the table (correct as they're owned by the logged-in user) and an automations filter option which incorrectly includes some automations not owned by the user (e.g. `test automation 3`)

[image]

Comment: A proper way is to add another model that stores the filter set by a user to separate business logic here

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to restrict the queryset to exclude messages that the logged-in user should not see

```
messages = account.message_set.exclude( something = whatever)
```

whatever will be be based on `request.user`. However, that will completely restrict what the user can see, not merely the initial default of what the user can see.

Another way is to "doctor" request.GET for initializing the filter. Instead of

```
filter = MessageFilter(request.GET, queryset=messages)
```

do

```
request_get = request.GET.copy()
# mutate request_get based on contents of request.GET and request.user
...
filter = MessageFilter(request_get, queryset=messages)
```

[request_get is mutable, unlike request.GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). You can inspect it to see what if any filters the user has requested. On the first view there won't be any, and you could insert some appropriate ones by assiging appropriate key/value pairs in
request_get. This way the user can override the initial defaults you choose for him.

Comment: Thanks for your post. The messages that are shown are already correct as they're owned by the current logged-in user. The issue is that when filtering, you can filter by automations that aren't owned by the user. Sorry if this was not made clear - I've added an image to the original question and more details explaining it